# Will the OID for a custom extend SNMP call be the same on multiple boxes?

Tags: linux, centos, snmp, snmpd, oid

CentOS 5.7 | SNMPD

This question is a little messy so I apologize in advance for any confusion.

I'm using the `extend` command in `/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf` to run a script.  I later used the `snmpwalk` utility to find the appropriate OID for this.

If I use the exact same command, script, relative paths, and OS will the OID be the same?  Or are OIDs unique to each server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The design of the Extend MIB is that you would query the `nsExtendConfigTable` looking for the index that corresponds to the correct name, specified in the `extend` directive.  Once you have that index, you can then query the tables `nsExtendOutput1Table` and `nsExtendOutput2Table`.

So, to answer your question, the OIDs will change, but are programmatically retrievable.