# extending snmp with static oid

Tags: snmp

I am attempting to extend snmp to return number of a given process

This is the tool, saved at /usr/bin/count_proc.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
ps aux | awk '
BEGIN { c=0 }
/processname$/ { c=c+1 }
END { print $c }'
```

in my snmpd.conf, I have the following line:

```
extend .1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.9999.1 count_proc /usr/bin/count_proc.sh
```

However, I am not able to retrieve the result of this command with this OID.
When I run a snmp query for this OID, the result is:

```
Value: (Snmp No Such object)
```

If I run traverse the snmp tree, I finally see something, but its strange... "Next OID" is the name of my tool, and not numeric at all.

```
OID: .1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.9999.1.2.1.2.9.99.111.117.110.116.95.102.119.100
Next OID: /usr/bin/count_proc.sh
Value: 1
```

And finally, I will see the value I am expecting.

```
OID: .1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.9999.1.3.1.1.9.99.111.117.110.116.95.102.119.100
Value: 13
```

But this is not the OID I expected to query to find the output. I will also find the output on several other OIDs.

Is this working as intended, or am I missing something important here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally I use extend without OID, like:

```
extend count_proc /usr/bin/count_proc.sh
```

The OID generated by snmp is simple, the result is:
*NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendOutput1Line.*”count_proc”

The OID is :
*1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.1.3.2.3.1.1*.**10.99.111.117.110.116.95.112.114.111.99**

Explanation :
`10  : number of character in "count_proc"
99  : ASCII decimal value of 'c'
111 : ASCII decimal value of 'o'
117 : ASCII decimal value of 'u'
110 : ASCII decimal value of 'n'
116 : ASCII decimal value of 't'
95  : ASCII decimal value of '_'
112 : ASCII decimal value of 'p'
114 : ASCII decimal value of 'r'
111 : ASCII decimal value of 'o'
99  : ASCII decimal value of 'c'`

So you can easily retrieve the OID programatically.

Answer (score -1):

Probably [This link](http://sysadminhq.wordpress.com/2009/01/28/cacti-graphing-custom-script-data-by-extending-snmp/) can help you in "extend" naming convention

Comment: Thanks, but if I understand the NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB correctly, the OID given will dynamically assigned, and I have to programatically find it. This scenario seems to be covered in http://serverfault.com/questions/374064/will-the-oid-for-a-custom-extend-snmp-call-be-the-same-on-multiple-boxes?rq=1