# extend snmp with static oid

Tags: shell, snmp

I encountered the same problem as you, did you finally solve it? I want to set a specific oid to specify the execution of a shell script, but the final oid changed.
the snmpd.conf is
https://image.taiche.eu.org/file/287c1ddcf54556938c4ba.png

but the oid changed
https://image.taiche.eu.org/file/758a7348dc25629f9ba41.png

Comment: Does this answer your question? [extending snmp with static oid](https://serverfault.com/questions/604330/extending-snmp-with-static-oid)

Comment: no, i need a definite oid，but it's not